# Storage usage configurations in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

Altering the broker configurations while migrating from ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis, struggling to find alternatives for the following system usage related configurations:

```xml
    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>
```

1. **memoryUsage** - found similar configuration "global-max-size", but is there a way to define it as a percentage of JVM Heap, like we used to in ActiveMQ Classic?
2. **storeUsage** - Seems like in Artemis you can configure "page-limit-bytes", but this setting seem to limit disc usage per address(queue)? Is there a similar configuration that would allow us to make sure that the entire broker doesn't use more disc that we allow it to use? (max-disk-usage configuration doesn't fully satisfy our needs since we collocate broker with other services and would want to clearly define the boundary that broker should never cross)
3. **tempUsage** - Not sure what this configuration is for, but are there any alternatives to it in Artemis?